# Menu <front> href not working

Tags: 7, navigation

I've never seen this problem in Drupal 7, but my home link contains the string `<front>` within its href. It's not working.

Any idea what could be happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal `<front>` is used to make a link which points to home page.. If you are in home page even if you click on that link you will come back to same page..

You can find the documentation about it in [URL](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) API function where it says..

> The special string `<front>` generates a link to the site's base URL.

URL function converts href from `<front`> to ''. So you should get baseurl in href. I see you are using spanish language, may be special characters in `<front>` is causing issue.. Can you make sure front word is utf-8 english supported letters..

After carefully watching your screenshot i see you are using [Void Menu](https://drupal.org/project/void_menu) module which is the root cause of your problem.. For solution see this [issue](https://drupal.org/node/2173269) in module Project Page..